(Chrome Extension) Unchecked runtime.lastError: Specified native messaging host not found
I've been trying for hours to set up a native messaging host connection between a simple Python file that reads in a message from my background.js file .But I'm getting continuous "Specified native messaging host not found" messages despite the Native Messaging Host existing and every file path being correct and existing.
My code:
Manifest.json (Native Messaging Host):
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "Native Messaging Host for my Python messaging Script",
    "path": "C:\Users\[My Name]\Downloads\Checkmate Extension\native_host\Model.py",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
      "chrome-extension://mhgbhgmbcbmjpoihiabgheefjeleniib/"
    ]
  }

Model.py:
import sys
import json

def main():
    message = json.loads(sys.stdin.readline())

    if message.get('type') == 'email_message':
        email_message = message.get('message')
        print("Received email message from Chrome extension:", email_message)

        response = {"response": "Message received successfully"}
        sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(response))
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Manifest.json (Extension):
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Checkmate",
    "version": "1.1",
    "permissions": [
      "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["popup.js", "authorized.js"]
        }
      ],
    "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
      }
  }
  

background.js:
// Connect to native messaging host
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('test');

// Send message to native messaging host
var message = { type: "email_message", message: "This is an example message." };
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('test', message, function(response) {
    console.log('Received response from native host:', response);
});

// Message received from native host
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  console.log('Message from native host:', message);
});

function onDisconnected() {
  console.log('Failed to connect: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
}

port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);


I have looked at Google's Documentation to no luck, following everything there. Im unsure if the folder layout is to blame but rearranging things did not yield any different results but the layout is:
Extension Folder-
native_host (Folder)-
Manifest.json
Model.py
Manifest.json
background.js
popup.js
As stated on Google's Documentation I've done
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\test" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\[My Name]\Downloads\Checkmate Extension\native_host\manifest.json" /f

on the command line. And opening Registry Editor confirms its location with "test" being displayed and the value data for default being the exact location that my manifest is on. Copying and Pasting this opens the manifest, so this is correct. The path on my manifest also opens the Python file directly, so it is also correct. I've restarted my device as a troubleshooting option, I have checked the extension key at least 10 times now to ensure it is absolutely correct, the name adheres to Google's Documentation requirement and the registry key is correct. Why am I still getting this issue?


path in json can be simply "Model.py", 2) Maybe Chrome can't run py files directly, so make a .bat file with python Model.py inside and specify this bat file in json.


Thank you but that did not resolve it. Now it just states that the connection is "disconnected"

Sounds like it actually helped and now you encountered a new problem: you're not reading stdin correctly. You need to read the length first, see the examples.
